Astro public subfolders not resolving
I setup a default Astro project, and wanted to make subfolders within /public however they are not available locally. As example:
/public/foobar.jpg resolves as <img src=/foobar.jpg/>
/public/images/foobar.jpg cannot be resolved

I build the project and rightfully so the dist will have "/images/foobar.jpg"
From the documentation i could not find anything to contradict the above approach, so appreciate any assistance

how are you trying to access it? where does the /public/images/foobar.jpg cannot be resolved error come from? does npm run preview work?

Apologies my formulation, but effectively when i place the image in a subfolder i get 404, despite the pathing being absolute.
Just now i was playing around with relative path trying to materialise a response and noticed that i used upper case I in "images"... im clearly getting rusty in my older days... apologies for the trouble
